# DatePickerDialog opens more than one time when touches EditText

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am using `DatePickerDialog` in my application. It is Fragment. Now, Issue is that when I couch on `EditText`, It open dialog 3 times.
I am using Total 2 `DatePickerDialog` for 2 different `EditText` and 2 `TimePickerDialog` for 2 different `EditText` here.

**My Code :**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

((EditText) etIOStartDate).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), StartDate, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    return false;
    }
});
}
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener StartDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            String myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat,
                    Locale.getDefault());

            ((EditText) etIOStartDate)
                    .setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }
    };
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. There are two events Action down and Action up.

```
((EditText) etIOStartDate).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(arg1.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), StartDate, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP  :
                break;

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @JeetenParmar you are welcome. If you still need something else pls specify that in your question. will be happy to answer

Comment: have u used Navigation Drawer Page sliding tab ? I need help for that

Comment: @JeetenParmar uses navigation drawer. but not tabs

Comment: ohkk, I need both as like Play Store.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50789/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-jeeten-parmar)

Answer (score 1):

just setOnClickListener to EditText

you have used setOnTouchListener so it finds 2-3 times touch so it will open

Comment: I was using setOnClickListener only, But use does not recognize it so then user can type anything in EditText.

Comment: @JeetenParmar did you try my suggestion??

Comment: Of course, It works but It is not as per my requirement because I already have it and I want to change it.

Comment: @JeetenParmar what is your requirement then. You din't metion anything in your question.

Comment: @Raghunandan, read post properly. And also check answers given by other users.

Comment: @JeetenParmar you read the question yourself you said dialog displays twice that is solved by my suggestion. Other that what else have you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

you have to maintain one global variable to check is your datepicker is opened or not. When you open datepicker assign that variable to true.

```
boolean isDatePickerOpened=false;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

((EditText) etIOStartDate).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(!isDatePickerOpened){

   isDatePickerOpened=true;
        new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), StartDate, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),       myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}
    return false;
    }
});
}


DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener StartDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            String myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat,
                    Locale.getDefault());

            ((EditText) etIOStartDate)
                    .setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

                isDatePickerOpened=false;

        }
    };
```

when date picker dialog dismissed you have to set that isDatePickerOpened to false. This may help you..

Comment: What if i want to open dialog again on touch ?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this under onCreate()**

```
txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSdate);
txtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            etSdate();
        }

});
```

**call this function in end of your program**

```
public void etSdate()
   {
       {

            // Process to get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // Display Selected date in textbox
                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();


  }
}
```